# iOS: in Swift3, in the UICollectionViewLayout section, how can I access to the main CollectionView properties?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When I am in the UICollectionViewLayout section, I can see that there is values in the main collectionView in my main class. The problem, is that I don't know how to access to the properties of the main class.

Example for the timeTable property:

Declaration in the main class:

```
import UIKit

@objc class PlanningViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let oneDay:TimeInterval = 24*60*60
    var typePlanning: String = "" //Type planning only in RENAULT_KADJAR

    //Size Array
    var timeTable : [[Int]] = []//property I want to access
    var uniqueValues : Array<Int> = []
    ...
```

In the UICollectionViewLayout, I see the value in the debug screen in "delegate":

[image]

I precise that I use two different classes with a storyboard.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your UICollectionViewLayout

```
let planningView = self.delegate as! PlanningViewController
var timeTable = planningView.timeTable
```

You can now access your data

Answer (score 0):

You can call self.collectionView from anywhere within the layout class and it will return the UICollectionView object that the layout belongs to.

Comment: I precise that I use two different classes with a storyboard. I don't see all the properties

Comment: What I want is to access to the properties of the class, it is not included in the collectionview

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is... from your screenshot I can see you have a property called delegate of type PlanningLayoutDelegate. If you want to access any property from here, just access by property.delegate